# Is there an Algorithmic Proof of $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x}$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x}$ holds if $f$ satisfies some conditions.

This fact is proved by analytic method.

Example:

$f(x, y) := x e^{x y}$.

$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} = 2 x e^{x y} + x^2 y e^{x y} = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x}$.

When we differentiate $f$ partially, we calculate parital derivatives of $f$ algorithmically.

We can also compute partial derivatives of $f$ by Matehmatica.

So, I wonder if there is an algorithmic or algebraic proof of this fact for functions like the above function.

Comment: Example $\neq$ Proof

Comment: There's an algorithm for the derivatives of elementary functions (and a few more), right. But are you sure there is one to decide if two functions are identical?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives

Comment: Thank you very much, Professor Vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few proofs that could be considered "algorithmic" or "algebraic." For example, one could take the Taylor expansion about a point at which $f$ is smooth, and show (algebraically) that the two derivatives are equal.

Extending this to points where $f$ is just twice differentiable would probably need an analytic argument, though...

Answer (score 2):

This is known as **Schwarz's Theorem**:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives

It sufficient that partial derivatives exist and are continuous.